# Swipe gestures with QML Stackview

Tags: qml, qt5, swipe, swipe-gesture

So QML StackView provides a way to navigate back by usin the `pop()` function. I am looking for a way to go the previous page by simply swiping to the right with UI elements following the fingers of the user (kind of like a `SwipeView`). How can I achieve this? I have looked around and all I found was this https://github.com/alejoasotelo/SwipePageStackWindow which is an old project that does a similar thing with the old `PageStack`.

Comment: You might try to use a `SwipeView` for that. Add a blank as second page, and when the index changes, pop it. Otherwise make the page draggable (with a `MouseArea`) and implement the swiping and the decision of the point of no return, speed and animations your self.

Comment: @derM I think the `SwipeView` is not really an alternative since my apps would contain at least 20 layers of "pages" so I would manually create and destroy the items to avoid performance issues. I thought about using a `MouseArea` and implement the gesture myself, but what I want the previous "page" to slide from the left as the user is swiping away the current item to the right. I don't understand how can get the previous "page" to do that. Does `StackView` provides a way to do that?

Comment: If your only trouble with using `SwipeView` *instead* of the `StackView` is the performance/memory issue, there is an example on how to load only three items are loaded at one time. You might also try to create a customized version of a `SwipeView` that automatically wraps added `Item`s in the appropriate `Loader`

Comment: Besides, with the `StackView` you already have *manual life time management of your items* - they live from *push* to *pop*

Comment: Yeah I understand that is doable in principle, but I would have to recreate all the functionalities of a `StackView` within a custom `SwipeView` and would also lose the ability to customize transitions when switching betwen pages (I suppose I could try to somehow recreate that too). This would require quite a lot of effort and I would prefer to leave this option as my last resort. I believe that `StackView` is really perfect, but the only thing I am missing is the ability to use swipe gestures in the way I described above.

Comment: Well, my initial idea was: Put `SwipeView`s with two items each on a `StackView`. The first Item is the real content, the second one is an empty Item. Then connect the `SwipeView`'s `indexChanged` to `pop()`. This would enable you to get the nice and smooth swipe effect which I found hard to engineer otherwise. On the other hand, ofc. it is a hack.

Comment: That seems like an idea that could work. Could you unpack that a little bit for me? Are you saying that I should create a `SwipeView` inside a `StackView`? Like this:
`StackView{
    id: stack
    SwipeView{
    .....
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to create a custom element called swiper that has a swipeview with 3 pages. 1 and 3 are blank but 2 has content. When page 1 is active, it allows all events to pass through unless a left swipe is detected. Page 2 has a loader So you can change the contents.

If you create two of these on top of each other you can move the one in front of the other whenever you need to switch views. Two loaders means the content will never consume too much memory.

So you'll have a variable isBottomActive

And one method
function pushNewView(view) <- this will move whichever swiper is not active to the front, put the view into it's loader and change currentIndex to 2.

Now if you need to go backwards you just swipe to the right. The swipers view index changes (you can tie a method here to make the old swipeview move back to the bottom with a different view as well)